# Designing flow for application

Tags: design, database, web-applications, websites, cloud

**Problem**

I am working on an application for my personal use. Basically what I require is a 24 hr running cloud application that will get alerted about the new articles posted on provided website links and fetch about heading or specific content from those articles. The info is processed and put together after which posted on my web app. As soon as this happens I should get a notification(web or SMS) in my phone. Now I can go and approve these posts personally on the web app. Approving them must send and store them to my google docs (or any similar platform). The post should die after my interaction.

**My approach**

I have done some research and broken down this into sub problems.

1. For getting the content I need to web scrap these websites. But I don't know how my application would know if a new article is posted. I think RSS feed can help but I am not sure.
2. For 24hr running app, I was thinking I can deploy a python script on a cloud platform like heroku. But would love to know if there is a better option that can integrate everything with my web app.
3. I can easily get notification in my phone from my web deployed web app.
4. For storing them on google docs part, I can use google app script. But I need to know if that can be easily integrated with everything else, as I haven't used it before.

**More info**

As this is for my personal use, I want it done in a cheapest way possible. The whole problem mentioned above is basically getting, processing and storing desired content from a website to my google sheet. I wanted to know all possible ways and constraints before I start working on it. Any help or suggestion as how I should do it is highly appreciable.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? Basically you write a program to do what you want, and the computer does it.

Comment: So an RSS feed from your favorite sites won't do the trick?

Comment: @user253751 I have mentioned what I want, and how I think I should approach. Before starting off myself, I wanted to make sure if this is the best possible way or any other much simpler solution is there?

Comment: I think you should write some code and see how far you can get and what you get stuck on. There is a specific question here, about what sort of things google app scripts can integrate with. That can be asked as a specific question, or answered by reading the documentation or experimenting.

Comment: @GregBurghardt RSS feed is the only thing I have come across till now, I don't know if there is any other way. I will go on with them only if that's the case.

Comment: @user253751 I will but question isn't really about getting stuck while coding the problem, rather what platform and resources best fit for the job.

Comment: Well in that case: Questions asking us to find or recommend tools, libraries, programming languages, resources (including books, blogs, tutorials, and examples), or projects to undertake are off-topic here as they attract opinionated answers that won't have lasting value to others.

Comment: @user253751 Is there any other SE site that accepts this sort of question or questions as such don't have any space in SE at all?

Comment: As far as I know, questions asking for recommendations about tools, libraries, languages, resources or projects to undertake are off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites.